# Windows 7 fails to connect to the internet a few minutes after startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

**Problem**

Earlier today, when I turned on my desktop computer, my internet connection works fine. Cryptocurrency miners connecting and hashing as usual and I can browse websites. But after  a few minutes, my miner fails indicating that there is *something wrong* with my internet connection. Tried refreshing my browser and is stuck at "resolving host", and then presented me an error. After that, i can't browse sites anymore. But the weird thing is that the network icon in Windows 7 shows no signs of problems.

**Solutions Made**

1. Restarted my computer without doing anything: Problem persists.
2. Tried using the network troubleshooter of windows: Reported no problems
3. Stopped bonjour still no progress.
4. Loaded windows using Last good config: still no progress.
5. Restarted Modem: No change.

**Current Status**

I currently did a system restore to my system to a point before installing the latest update from Microsoft. Because earlier today, I installed some updates and after that, the problem started to appear. (After system restore, same problem.)

**Latest Programs installed before the problem**

MS Visual Studio 2013 (but internet still worked fine after the install).

I hope someone could provide answers on this problem. It is my first time encountering this.

**EDIT**: Additional Info

1. OS: Windows 7 SP1 64-bit
2. AV: Avast Free Antivirus
3. Internet Connection Type: Ethernet
4. It appears that my Laptop can't even connect to the machine thru Remote Desktop
5. My laptop and phone on WiFi works fine and can connect to the internet.

**EDIT 2:** Whenever I boot into Safe Mode, my Internet is fine.

**EDIT 3 :** I think chrome is the culprit. I tried CCleaner but same problem persists.

**EDIT 4:** I reformatted my computer. I think something in chrome corrupted some system files.

Answer (score 0):

What are your network adapter power settings set to? For some daft reason, even if you are generating traffic, your network adapter can get turned to standby...

Comment: Nope. I did not change anything to the network adapter power setting.

Comment: You will need to change them as, by default, they are set to go to sleep...

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache using a program like CCleaner or Wise 365, if windows is saying there internet access it means it is able to ping and it just a browser issue.

COnfirm connection by opening command prompt and ping bbc.co.uk

Answer (score -1):

Try using an ethernet through your router, if that works restart your computer then change it back to wifi. If it still doesnt work, restart your router and reset your computers wifi.

Comment: My computer is a desktop one, so I can't test in on WiFi.

Comment: @BUDDEH - This really seems like it should have been a comment, and if it worked, then turned into an answer.